# Update error and Basic Auth / Symfony errors

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I'm running 2 servers: TEST and PROD. I've been using Composer to install updates. They are running on Windows Server 2016 using IIS. I copied composer.json and composer.lock from TEST over to PROD. They were installed using the version 8 recommended project.

Note that I'm just administering the web server for a developer and I don't know anything about modifications they've made.

I tried to perform an update on both servers but ran into a roadblock. TEST worked (8.9.1 to 8.9.3), but PROD failed (8.6.3 to 8.9.3), so I rolled both back. (The out of sync versions between TEST and PROD is from a recent update I did on TEST, but I hadn't replicated the update process on PROD yet. I updated TEST to 8.9.1 in June but not PROD at that time.)

This is the error within PROD's Git Bash terminal for the Composer update attempt, for this recent update.

> CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 31: The service
> "basic auth.authentication.basic auth" has a dependency on a
> non-existent service "user.auth".

I didn't see this error when I updated TEST to 8.9.1 or 8.9.3.

Note that I also saw a *drush updatedb terminated abnormally* error, but this could be unrelated.

I couldn't find anything online about the above Auth error, so I tried to plow through it with a forced update, knowing I could roll back to a virtual machine snapshot. The update finished, but then the PROD web admin console wouldn't load at all and had this error.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

I then edited the settings.php file to display errors. The result was this when the site's admin page was loaded.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
> You have requested a non-existent service "authentication". in
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition()
> (line 1060 of
> D:\www\drupal8\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\ContainerBuilder.php).
>
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition('authentication')
> (Line: 620)
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet('authentication',
>
> 1. (Line: 588)
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('authentication')
>    (Line: 179) Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handleAccess(Object,
>    Object) (Line: 102) Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handleRaw(Object)
>    (Line: 76) Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 28)

I didn't know what to do, so I reverted back to the virtual machine snapshot, and that's where it currently sits.

As a test, I copied the db and files/folders from PROD to a local test virtual machine to give me more freedom to play around with it, and I am seeing this error just after the initial copy, no update attempted yet.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::replace() must be of
> the type array, null given, called in
> C:\www\drupal8test\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider.php
> on line 171 in
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag->replace() (line 59 of
> C:\www\drupal8test\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\ParameterBag.php).
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag->replace(NULL) (Line:
> 171)
> Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteCollectionForRequest(Object)
> (Line: 239)
> Drupal\Core\Routing\Router->getInitialRouteCollection(Object) (Line:
> 123) Drupal\Core\Routing\Router->matchRequest(Object) (Line: 92)
> Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->matchRequest(Object) (Line:
> 113)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object,
> 'kernel.request', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object,
> 'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 111)
> Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
> Object) (Line: 127)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line:
> 68) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> (Line: 57) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> (Line: 47) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object,
> 1, 1) (Line: 191)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object, 1, 1)
> (Line: 128)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object, 1, 1)
> (Line: 82) Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object,
> 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1,
>
> 1. (Line: 52)
>    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1,
> 2. (Line: 23) Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
> 3. Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

What might be the problem with the update? What is the problem that's causing the error on the clone to a different test environment?

Comment: Have you cleared cache after the code change? Sometimes new dependencies are added or change and a cache clear is needed before running database updates

Comment: Yeah, I usually run "drush cache:rebuild" after enabling maintenance mode, right before updating Drupal, and then afterwards.

Comment: what did drush up db do ?

Comment: I don't have all of the output or history saved because I reverted back to the snapshot but I think "drush updatedb" gave a relatively generic 'terminated abnormally' error.

Comment: Also any thoughts on why a clone to a different VM would produce the error listed at the bottom of the post?